# Event for when UI is shown to user?

Tags: android, loading, splash-screen

I would like my main activity to load a loading message. Once this is displayed i would like to start my tab activity which has to load a fairly heavy RSS feed. Problem is i have tried overriding onStart and onWindowFocusChanged if hasFocus but neither draw the view before starting the other activity.
Anyone know how to do this? All the splash screen examples use a timer which is not what i want to do, i want it to stay while the data is loading and clear itself when the onPause is fired.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start another activity while you're still showing another one. You have to change you control flow.

Load you RSS feed with an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) while you're still in your main activity showing the loading message. When you finished loading all the data you need, [store it somewhere](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), then start you tab activity. So you tab activity don't need to load the data itself but can fetch it from the place you stored it.